# fast scroll list - problems with the alphabetic list in the right

Tags: android, scroll, android-contacts

I want to create a contact list with fast scroll. In the right I need to place the alphabetic list"ABCD...Z". On the screen I need to pop up the A, or B...everytime I click on the right list or..scroll up and down.

In my code: I have 2 problems:
 First the alphabetic list image disappears when I scroll down the list a
  Secondly on the screen doesn't appear anything if I click in the middle of the list, for example. I mean I need to put my finder on the scroll button in order to see the down list characters when going though the list. I don't want that button when scrolling to be visible and I also want it to be activated in the place where i put my finder.

Got any advices?

**.java**

```
            class MyIndexerAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> implements SectionIndexer {

                    ArrayList<String> myElements;
                    HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;

                    String[] sections;

                    public MyIndexerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                    List<T> objects) {


                            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                            myElements = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
                            // here is the tricky stuff
                            alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                            // in this hashmap we will store here the positions for
                            // the sections

                            int size = elements.size();
                            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                    String element = elements.get(i);
                                    alphaIndexer.put(element.substring(0, 1), i);
                            //We store the first letter of the word, and its index.
                            //The Hashmap will replace the value for identical keys are putted in
                            }


                            Set<String> keys = alphaIndexer.keySet(); // set of letters ...sets       
                            Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
                            ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(); // list can be
                            // sorted

                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                    String key = it.next();
                                    keyList.add(key);
                            }

                            Collections.sort(keyList);

                            sections = new String[keyList.size()]; // simple conversion to an
                            // array of object
                            keyList.toArray(sections);


                    }


                    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
                            // Log.v("getPositionForSection", ""+section);
                            String letter = sections[section];

                            return alphaIndexer.get(letter);
                    }

                    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {

                            // you will notice it will be never called (right?)
                            Log.v("getSectionForPosition", "called");
                            return 0;
                    }

                    public Object[] getSections() {

                            return sections; // to string will be called each object, to display                        }

            }
    }
```